# llvm OCaml bindings

Tags: ocaml, llvm, opam

I'm working on llvm OCaml bindings.

I installed llvm package through opam (`opam install llvm`), when I use llvm in utop, I get the following error:

```
#require "llvm";;
Error: The external function 'llvm_global_succ' is not available.
```

The opam llvm version is 3.2.

I also tried building llvm3.3 from the official site (`./configure --with-ocaml-libdir='ocamlc -where'`), the build was successful (all the llvm command-line tools are working), but I got the same error in utop.

I'm on Mac OS 10.7.5.

---

#### Edit: I solved it..

`ocamlmktop -o llvmtop llvm.cma -cc g++`

Then launch `llvmtop`, you can use llvm bindings after `open Llvm`.

I haven't found an equivalent for `utop` yet..

---

#### Edit2: Now `utop` is working!

Thanks to the `utop` documentation [here](https://github.com/diml/utop)

1. create a `myutop_main.ml` file:

   `let () = UTop_main.main ()`
2. create a custom `utop` with llvm bindings:

   `ocamlfind ocamlmktop -o llvmutop -thread -linkpkg -package utop -package llvm myutop_main.ml -cc g++`

Comment: Since you've solved the problem yourself, please move your solution from the question into an answer and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as answered.

Comment: @xysun - can you cut your own answer from your question above, and paste it into an answer, and then mark it as answered? That way it will be removed from the _Unanswered Questions_ list. Many Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(as I'm asked to answer my own question...)

#### To use system toplevel

`ocamlmktop -o llvmtop llvm.cma -cc g++`

Then launch `llvmtop`, you can use llvm bindings after `open Llvm`.

I haven't found an equivalent for `utop` yet..

---

#### To use `utop`

Thanks to the `utop` documentation [here](https://github.com/diml/utop)

1. create a `myutop_main.ml` file:

   `let () = UTop_main.main ()`
2. create a custom `utop` with llvm bindings:

   `ocamlfind ocamlmktop -o llvmutop -thread -linkpkg -package utop -package llvm myutop_main.ml -cc g++`